# Outlook Anywhere using the wrong URL

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010, windows-sbs-2011, outlook-anywhere

We've configured Outlook 2010 to use Outlook Anywhere and it works fine against SBS 2011 Std. However, on start-up, it complains about a mismatched certificate.

After a bit of sniffing with Fiddler2, we've learned that, in spite of being given a URL of support.ourdomain.com for Outlook Anywhere (for which we have a proper cert), Outlook is still going off to remote.ourdomain.com during the autodiscover phase — hence the invalid cert warning.

Why is Outlook using a different URL for autodiscover, and how can we change it to use the correct one?

Comment: From memory, you need to assign each individual certificate for each service, which can be done in the management console, or via powershell.

Comment: @Mark: Thank you for the suggestion. However, the certificate being delivered is the one I want (we don't have one for remote.ourdomain.com). It's the URL that's incorrect. Or have I misunderstood your advice?

Comment: Sorry, I mis-understood your question. Now that I re-read it, the autodiscover URL is wrong. You'll need to set that up in the powershell interface, but I can't remember the commands.

Comment: @Mark: Thank you. Your advice set me on the right track (see my answer), and it's working beautifully now.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to the pointers provided by Mark Henderson, I finally nailed this one. I had to change two objects in EMS:

```
Set-WebServicesVirtualDirectory -identity "ourserver\ews (Default Web Site)" `
    -InternalUrl https://support.ourdomain.au/EWS/Exchange.asmx `
    -ExternalUrl https://support.ourdomain.au/EWS/Exchange.asmx

Set-ClientAccessServer -identity ourserver `
    -AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri https://support.ourdomain.au/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml
```

I also came across advice to set the following:

```
Set-AutodiscoverVirtualDirectory -identity "ourserver\Autodiscover (Default Web Site)" `
    -InternalUrl https://support.ourdomain.au/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml `
    -ExternalUrl https://support.ourdomain.au/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml
```

But this didn't seem to be necessary in our case (though I changed it afterwards anyway).